# Using Heikin Ashi data from an alternative ticker and timeframe

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am attempting to use Heikin Ashi data from an alternative ticker and timeframe in my strategy as an on/off switch......is this possible?

```
//@version=5
indicator("HA Close", "", true)

res2 = input.timeframe(title='Time Frame', defval='', group="ON/OFF")
supportSymbol = input.symbol('ETHUSDT', title='Correlated Symbol', group="ON/OFF")
supportTicker = request.security(supportSymbol, res2, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)  //input(close, title="Source")
ha_open2 = request.security(supportTicker, ticker.heikinashi, res2, (open)[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
ha_high2 = request.security(supportTicker, ticker.heikinashi, res2, (high)[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
ha_low2 = request.security(supportTicker, ticker.heikinashi, res2, (low)[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
ha_close2 = request.security(supportTicker, ticker.heikinashi, res2, (close)[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
//plotcandle(isInfoboxA and ha_open2 < ha_close2 ? (ha_open2) : na, ha_high2, ha_low2, ha_close2, title='Green Candles', color=#53b987, wickcolor=#53b987, bordercolor=#53b987)
//plotcandle(isInfoboxA and ha_open2 >= ha_close2 ? (ha_open2) : na, ha_high2, ha_low2, ha_close2, title='Red Candles', color=#eb4d5c, wickcolor=#eb4d5c, bordercolor=#eb4d5c)
//color1=ha_close2>ha_open2?color.new(color.green,0):color.new(color.red,0)

RED = ha_open >= ha_close

off = RED

if (na(off))
    strategy.cancel_all()
    strategy.close_all()
```

I've tried different variations of the above.  Receiving errors that I can not fix with my limited knowledge.  In looking, I can't see where this has been attempted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You just need to create a new ticker id with the `ticker.heikinashi()` function.

Example:

```
heikinashi_close = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)
```